# How to fix this issue with Sass in my React project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, dart-sass

So i've been trying (without sucess) for 2 days straight every possible way of using sass in my project.
I'm using 7-1 architecture for sass and a basic components-layout-pages architecture for the javascript.

The problem is i keep getting this error :

`Failed to compile ./src/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/sass/main.scss) Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93) For more information on which environments are supported please see: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v5.0.0 This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.`

From what i've understood almost all sass compiler are deprecated and i found out that Dart sass might be the best one so i've been installing it and setting up the script, however even if most of the compiler did compile the code just fine, my app won't load...

I don't know what to do about it and can't wrap my head around it.
so i'm here begging for your help.

By the way I read almost all question related to sass dart sass node and react on here and havent found an answer to mine.
If you need some more details about the code please let me know.

Comment: Since you're using React, I suspect you're using Webpack, whereby you may use [`sass-loader`](https://npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) along with the [`sass`](https://npmjs.com/package/sass) (Dart SASS) package to make your life a lot easier. See https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/.

Comment: Yes i use webpack, i already tried installing sass-loader, without sucess,however by reading the doc you just linked i realized there was another way to install it : for now it seems to work i add a log saying it was a problem with the version declared and the one that was used ( of webpack ) and explaining how to fix it.I'm currently triying it out.

Comment: so from what i figured out it was the wrong version of webpack in my package.json from the one i had in my nodes_modules, however it still didnt work, so i tried importing my src and public folder in a freshly created react-app  with the package i needed and it seems to work from now so i guessed i must have messed up my dependency tree and package.json... Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please elaborate ? what would be needed ? i'ts just that i messed up my dependencies and had to go for a new create react app.I don't even know myself where the error exactly came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing sass loader this way `yarn add -D sass-loader sass webpack` and the matching webpack version.

This is the actual package.Json file right now:

```
    {
  "name": "cyzbot-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "dart compile-sass.dart ./src/main.scss ./src/main.css",
    "prefix": "postcss ./src/main.css --use autoprefixer -d ./public/css/prefixed/",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  }
}
```

Edit: it just happenned again  and thanks god i posted the package when it was fixed...

So I just figured out the issue came from me triyong to do an 'npm audit fix' and or 'npm audit fix --force' and there's the code it outputed as i was trying to restart the server:

```
    react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.        
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a 
dependency:

  "webpack": "4.28.3"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in 
the tree:

  C:\Users\Work\Documents\Code\CyzBot-React\node_modules\webpack (version: 5.73.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in 
the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try: 

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\Work\Documents\Code\CyzBot-React\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something 
in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above 
:-) We hope you find them helpful!
```

And it seems it tried switching back to an older version of react script ( for security issues ) but like 2.1.3 ??

It makes it seems like it's an error from webpack when in fact it's just that the only version of webpack that looks like to be working with that version of react-script is : "webpack": "4.28.3".

So if you just delete your package in node_modules modify the react-script version to the one you use(d) then do `yarn install` or `npm install` then start the local server again it should work back now.

At least it did for me.